# how to setup Karma with Ui5

Tags: karma-runner, sapui5

I have a question related to karma and ui5. 
Current situation is as follows:

I use karma-openui5 and load ui5 via bower. Karma-openui5 simply adds some bootstrap information and the core-file itself:

```
files.unshift({pattern: ui5path, included: true, watched: false, served: true});
```

which leads to this head entry:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/base/bower_components/openui5-sap.ui.core/resources/sap-ui-core.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Ui5 is designed to load everything else related to the core-file but is served by sap in different bower packages this means, request is:

> http://localhost:9876/base/bower_components/**openui5-sap.ui.core**/resources/sap/m/library-preload.js

but it's actually located under

> http://localhost:9876/base/bower_components/**openui5-sap.m**/resources/sap/m/library-preload.js

I could overcome this problem with proxy entries. But i can`t include the .css files which one are in a separate bower package. I can't see a way to proxy only */**/*.css* requests to another directory. Therefore this way just doesn't work well.

Openui5 has already some middleware (connect-openui5) to resolve this problems and server everything as expected  under localhost:XXXX/resources/.

How and can i add custom script tags in karma? like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/sap-ui-core.js"></script>
```

How can i add a middleware (connect-openui5) to handle all requests to /resources/**/*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use the connect middleware from sap, started with grunt and proxy to this.

I packed everything in a yeoman generator, if anyone is interested in the setup.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-ui5